# svnadmin add new user and assign it only one repo

Tags: svn, debian, svnadmin

I will create a new user on my svn server, which can access only in one of my repository. It's possible?

My server runs debian squeeze.

Comment: Everything's possible, except what's impossible ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set permissions using svn authz file. First of all, we need to create an Access Control file.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/svn_access_control
```

User Groups

You can create groups of users and then use those for rules. You do this under a special heading in square brackets:

```
[groups]
mygroup = dave, mike
```

This will create a group called ‘mygroup’ which ‘dave’ and ‘mike’ belongs to.

And now for some examples. Examples

```
[groups]
team = bob, bill devteam = bob, barry, brett
[/]
@team = r bob = rw
[/wowapp/trunk]
@team = r @devteam = rw brenda = rw
```

In this example:

```
Created a group team which has two members; bob and bill.
Created another group, called devteam which has three members; bob, barry, brett.
In the root of the repository, I’ve given the group team read permissions.
Also, in the root, bob has read and write permissions.
In the trunk of wowapp, the group team has read permission.
Also, the devteam group has read and write permissions.
And another user, called brenda has read and write permissions.
```

You need to add is the following line in apache svn configuration file.

```
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn_access_control
```

So that the file looks like this:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /home/svn

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn_access_control

  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Save the file, and then restart Apache2:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

You should now have access control working for Subversion over Apache2.

Answer (score -1):

For per directory authenticated access see the [auth section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn) of the redbean book.

If you want something easier you could use something with a GUI to set access permissions, such as [uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/).